# EPPlus - when saving it omits the value for a cell with a function that returns an empty string

Tags: epplus

Excel has some functions that can return an empty string, e.g.

```
IF(ISBLANK(A1),"","Not blank")
```

CONCAT or CONCATENATE are other obvious examples that can return "".

When an Excel workbook with such a function is saved (without making any modifications) and reloaded, the cell value changes from an empty string "", to null within EPPlus.

This has been tested with EPPlus v6.2.6 (built from source) and v6.2.7 via NuGet.

I didn't expect to see the cell's value change from "" to null. Re-opening in Excel doesn't show the change, presumably because it recalculates the value on loading. However, looking at the XML the `<v>` element is present in the original file (created via Excel) and is omitted after saving with EPPlus.

It appears to result from the code in `ExcelXmlWriter.GetFormulaValue(object v, string prefix)` which does not output a `<v>` element when the string value is "".

**Is this expected behaviour or a bug?**

**Steps to reproduce**. First create a new empty workbook in Excel and put the formula

```
=IF(ISBLANK(A1),"","Not blank")
```

in cell B1. Save as origIf.xlsx, then run the following

```
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using OfficeOpenXml;

static void Investigate()
{
    const string baseDir = @"U:\Test\EPPlus_Null"; // ADJUST AS NEEDED
    const string origFile = "origIf.xlsx";
    const string saveFile = "nomod-saved.xlsx";
    ExcelPackage.LicenseContext = LicenseContext.NonCommercial;
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Original workbook");
        using (var excelPackage = new ExcelPackage(Path.Combine(baseDir, origFile))) {
            ExcelRange a1Cell = excelPackage.Workbook.Worksheets["Sheet1"].Cells[1, 1];
            ExcelRange b1Cell = excelPackage.Workbook.Worksheets["Sheet1"].Cells[1, 2];
            ReportValue(a1Cell);
            ReportValue(b1Cell);
            excelPackage.SaveAs(Path.Combine(baseDir, saveFile));
        }
        Debug.WriteLine("Saved workbook");
        using (var excelPackage = new ExcelPackage(Path.Combine(baseDir, saveFile))) {
            ExcelRange a1Cell = excelPackage.Workbook.Worksheets["Sheet1"].Cells[1, 1];
            ExcelRange b1Cell = excelPackage.Workbook.Worksheets["Sheet1"].Cells[1, 2];
            ReportValue(a1Cell);
            ReportValue(b1Cell);
        }
    }
}

static void ReportValue(ExcelRange cell)
{
    Debug.Write(cell.Address);
    if (cell.Value is null)
        Debug.WriteLine(" value is null");
    else if (cell.GetCellValue<string>() == "") {
        Debug.WriteLine(" value is empty string");
    }
    else {
        Debug.WriteLine(" value is " + cell.GetCellValue<string>());
    }
}
```

**For me the output was**

```
Original workbook
A1 value is null
B1 value is empty string
Saved workbook
A1 value is null
B1 value is null
```

Note the change in B1 from empty string to null.

**Original XML created by Excel 2019**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<worksheet xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main" xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" mc:Ignorable="x14ac xr xr2 xr3" xmlns:x14ac="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/spreadsheetml/2009/9/ac" xmlns:xr="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/spreadsheetml/2014/revision" xmlns:xr2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/spreadsheetml/2015/revision2" xmlns:xr3="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/spreadsheetml/2016/revision3" xr:uid="{00000000-0001-0000-0000-000000000000}">
    <dimension ref="B1"/>
    <sheetViews>
        <sheetView tabSelected="1" workbookViewId="0">
            <selection activeCell="B1" sqref="B1"/>
        </sheetView>
    </sheetViews>
    <sheetFormatPr defaultRowHeight="15" x14ac:dyDescent="0.25"/>
    <sheetData>
        <row r="1" spans="2:2" x14ac:dyDescent="0.25">
            <c r="B1" t="str">
                <f>IF(ISBLANK(A1),"","Not blank")</f>
                <v/>
            </c>
        </row>
    </sheetData>
    <pageMargins left="0.7" right="0.7" top="0.75" bottom="0.75" header="0.3" footer="0.3"/>
</worksheet>
```

Note the presence of the (empty) `<v>` element.

**XML created by EPPlus**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<worksheet xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main" xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" mc:Ignorable="x14ac xr xr2 xr3" xmlns:x14ac="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/spreadsheetml/2009/9/ac" xmlns:xr="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/spreadsheetml/2014/revision" xmlns:xr2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/spreadsheetml/2015/revision2" xmlns:xr3="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/spreadsheetml/2016/revision3" xr:uid="{00000000-0001-0000-0000-000000000000}">
    <dimension ref="B1"/>
    <sheetViews>
        <sheetView tabSelected="1" workbookViewId="0">
            <selection activeCell="B1" sqref="B1"/>
        </sheetView>
    </sheetViews>
    <sheetFormatPr defaultRowHeight="15" x14ac:dyDescent="0.25"/>
    <sheetData>
        <row r="1">
            <c r="B1" s="0" t="str">
                <f>IF(ISBLANK(A1),"","Not blank")</f>
            </c>
        </row>
    </sheetData>
    <pageMargins left="0.7" right="0.7" top="0.75" bottom="0.75" header="0.3" footer="0.3"/>
    <headerFooter/>
</worksheet>
```

Note the absence of the `<v>` element.

Comment: What version of the `EPPlus` is used?

Comment: @Jackdaw This has been tested with EPPlus v6.2.6 (built from source) and v6.2.7 via NuGet. Have added to details above.